# My Lumen dependency does not recognize $router in api.php - Undefined variable: router

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have microservice written in `Lumen (8.2.3)`.

This microservice has some routes and all seems to work.

In `my-microservice/routes/api.php` I have:

```php
<?php

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router;

/** @var Router $router */
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/', 'IndexController@index');
    [cut]
```

Now, this microservice requires my external dependency and this dependency also has one route:

```php
<?php

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router;

/** @var Router $router */
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('reset-progress', 'ACME\MyExternalPackage\Http\Controllers\ResetProgressController@resetProgress');
});
```

Now as soon as it's successfully installed via composer, and added into `bootstrap/app.php`:

```
$app->register(ACME\MyExternalPackage\Providers\ResetProgressServiceProvider::class);
```

and I type `php artisan` I get:

> $ php artisan
>
> In api.php line 6:
>
> Undefined variable: router

Line 6 points to:

```php
<?php

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router;

/** @var Router $router */
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) { <----- this is line 6 in vendor
    $router->post('reset-progress', 'ACME\MyExternalPackage\Http\Controllers\ResetProgressController@resetProgress');
});
```

When I comment this register line in `bootstrap\app.php` it works again.
What am I doing wrong? The namespaces is consistent and "clickable" in my PhpStorm.

My vendor package has in `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8"
},
```

Comment: how are you loading this new route file?

Answer (score 1):

In your bootstrap/app/php file, at the bottom of the file, you have this code:

```
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php';
});

return $app;
```

you need to register your api.php file here under the web.php